# How to retrieve data from the Content Picker with Razor?

Tags: razor, umbraco

I try to use the Content picker w/o success..

I created a doc type which the properties are Content pickers, so what I try to do is along the magazine to use this page to pick up the features news / etc and display them on home page. w/o success..

I used something like:

```
dynamic feature_news_item = Library.NodeById(1111); (tried also the same but with Model: Model.NodeById(1111); Let's say for the example that 1111 is the id of this page which store the content pickers.
```

So again, the property of the page is "Content Picker" and the alias is featureItemNews

Now, I try to get / display the ID which the Content Picker (as much as I know..) should retrieve but just get errors (or nothing...) - tried this for example:

```
var node = @Library.NodeById(feature_news_item.contentPicker);
<a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a>
```

Doesn't show the Url nor the Name

So I tried

```
var node = @Library.NodeById(feature_news_item.featureItemNews);
 int story1 = @feature_story.featureItemNews
```

Nothing works
Again featureItemNews is the Alias
and feature_news_item is just to get the Node with the Content picker (see at the beginning of the question)

All I try now is just to get the ID of the selected node which store in the content picker and display it / use it
What's the magic?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. I've added Content Picker with alias (and name): myTestContentPicker
2. In razor code
   :

   ```
   var current = umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent();

   int id = current.GetProperty<int>("myTestContentPicker");

   < h1>@id< /h1>
   ```

It shows the ID of node I have selected. Then I can do whatever I want with this node:

```
var node = new Node(id);
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to get this property from other page - not the current. So I tried instead Node myNode                 = new Node(1234); and then string myValue              = myNode.GetProperty("featureItemNews").Value; Not work ...

Comment: There is no such code as "string myValue = myNode.GetProperty("featureItemNews").Value;" in my example. I have tested it with "int id = current.GetProperty("myTestContentPicker");"

Do you mind using int and not using .Value for the sake of experiment please?